# Showing that $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{F})$ and $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{F_1})$ are diffeomorphic but $\mathscr{F}\neq \mathscr{F_1}$

Tags: differential-geometry

**Background**

$M$ is *locally Euclidean* with dimension $d$ if $M$ is hausdorff and every point in $M$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R{^d}}$. If $U\subset M$ is open and connected and $\phi$ a homeomorphism (called a *coordinate map*) of $U$ onto an open $M\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, then $(U,\phi)$ is a *coordinate system*.

A *differentiable structure* $\mathscr{F}$ of class $C^k$ $(1 \leq k \leq \infty)$ on a locally Euclidean space $M$ is a collection of coordinate systems $\{(U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha): \alpha \in A\}$ satisfying the following properties:

1. $\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} U_\alpha=M$
2. $\phi_a \circ \phi_\beta^{-1}$ is $C^k$ for all $\alpha,\beta \in A$
3. If $(U,\phi)$ is a coordinate system such that $\phi \circ \phi_{\alpha}^{-1}$ and $\phi_\alpha \circ \phi^{-1}$ are $C^k$ for all $\alpha \in A$, then $(U,\phi) \in \mathscr{F}$

If $\mathscr{F}_0=\{ (U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha): \alpha \in A\}$ then the *maximal differentiable structure* containing $\mathscr{F}_0$ is given by $$\mathscr{F}=\{(U,\phi):\phi \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1} \ \mathrm{and} \ \phi_{\alpha} \circ \phi^{-1} \ \mathrm{are}\ C^k \ \mathrm{for \ all} \   \phi_{\alpha} \in \mathscr{F}_0\}$$

A *differentiable manifold of class* $C^k$ is a pair $(M,\mathscr{F})$ of a second countable, locally euclidean space $M$ and a differentiable structure $\mathscr{F}$ of class $C^k$.

If $M$ and $N$ are differentiable manifolds, then $\psi:M\rightarrow N$ is a diffeomorphism if $\psi$ is one-to-one and onto and $\psi^{-1}$ is $C^{\infty}$, in the sense that $\phi \circ \psi \circ \tau^{-1}$ is $C^{\infty}$, where $\phi$ is a coordinate map on $N$ and $\tau$ a coordinate map on $M$.

**Question**

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the maximal collection of coordinate systems containing $(\mathbb{R},id)$, where $id$ is the identity map and let $\mathscr{F_1}$ be the maximal differentiable structure containing $(\mathbb{R},\phi)$, where $\phi$ is given by $t \rightarrow t^3$.
Show that $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{F})$ and $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{F_1})$ are diffeomorphic but $\mathscr{F}\neq \mathscr{F_1}$.

**Attempt**

If $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{F}_1$ then the composition $id \circ \phi^{-1}=t^{1/3}$ would be $C^k$. However, $t^{1/3}$ is not differentiable at the origin. Next, let $\psi:(\mathscr{R},id) \rightarrow (\mathscr{R},\phi)$ be defined by $t\rightarrow t^{1/3}$ Then $\psi$ is one to one and onto. Furthermore, 
$$id \circ \psi^{-1} \circ \phi^{-1}$$ is the identity function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore it is $C^{\infty}$. Consequently, the two manifolds are diffeomorphic.

Is my attempt correct? Am I understanding correctly the difference between the differentiable structure and the manifold on it?